# Getting error in camera react native "null is not an object"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

[image: This error am getting]
// I am using camera in QRCodeScanner , below is my package.json file , I have install all the dependencies and permission in manifest file .
But while building react-native run-android its loading 100% but getting this error "null is not an object(evaluating 'cameramanager.aspect')"

```
{
      "name": "Vmedics",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
        "native-base": "^2.10.0",
        "react": "16.6.3",
        "react-native": "0.58.4",
        "react-native-camera": "^1.8.0",
        "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",
        "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.17.0",
        "react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.7",
        "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.1.2",
        "react-native-ratings": "^6.3.0",
        "react-native-svg": "^9.2.4",
        "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.2.0",
        "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.0",
        "react-navigation": "^3.2.1",
        "react-router": "^4.3.1",
        "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
        "jest": "24.1.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
      },
      "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
      }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried linking react-native-camera manually? Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner/issues/109)

Comment: what i did is .. i create project and then install all these dependencies ,and when am doing react-native run-android ,then its coming ..

Comment: Ok. According to the issue I linked someone resolved your problem by linking react-native-camera manually. I mean doing [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera#ios)

Comment: Let me try ..Thanks @Milore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ..
1.npm install react-native-camera --save
2. Android - src- manifest -
3. Settings.gradle - include ':react-native-camera'
project(':react-native-camera').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-camera/android')

3.Android - app- build.gradle - compile project(':react-native-camera')

4. Android - app -src-main-java-com- MainApplication.java-

import org.reactnative.camera.RNCameraPackage;

```
@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new RNCameraPackage(),
               );
```

Comment: Your answer is not understandable can you please wirete as codes more understandable?